# USB wireless adapter connects fine, but no access (16.04)

Tags: networking, usb, internet

The adapter (Alfa AWUS036H) is detected and the system shows that is connected to my router. I installed drivers manually.

However I don't have internet access. Pinging anything (even the router itself at 192.168.0.1) fails. Here's some `ifconfig` info:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:119010 (119.0 KB)  TX bytes:119010 (119.0 KB)

wlx00c0ca83007e Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:83:00:7e  
          inet addr:192.168.0.7  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5bf1:11b3:af49:502a/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:14d:8400:3e00:4d8e:2bc1:775:13d7/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:147334 (147.3 KB)  TX bytes:133256 (133.2 KB)
```

`wlx00c0ca83007e` is the USB adapter. Here's `nmcli device show wlx00c0ca83007e` output:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx00c0ca83007e
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:C0:CA:83:00:7E
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     <SSID HERE>
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.7/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             75.75.75.75
IP4.DNS[2]:                             75.75.76.76
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2601:14d:8400:3e00:4d8e:2bc1:775:13d7/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fe80::5bf1:11b3:af49:502a/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::6655:b1ff:fe38:e21e
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2601:14d:8400:3e00::/60, nh = fe80::6655:b1ff:fe38:e21e, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2601:14d:8400:3e00::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2001:558:feed::1
IP6.DNS[2]:                             2001:558:feed::2
```

Any idea what is going on here?